# MYSQL : Order By on Two column

Tags: sorting

I am bit new to MYSQL. I want to sort Dataset(SQL output) results on two column depending on user selection.

In my table, I have following two column related to Processing Charges:

```
1:  Proc_Percentage  - Float

2:  Proc_Fees.       - Float
```

Each row will have value for EITHER of one Column.

```
For example 1% or 2345 $. 

Another example 1.5% or 678 $ like that.
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Row 1:  1%     NULL

Row 2:  NULL   2345

Row 3:  1.5%   NULL

Row 4:  NULL   678

Row 5:  0.5%   NULL

Row 6:  NULL   1234
```

*Please note that None of above row contain vlaue for both the column

On the front end, I have a DROP DOWN where user can sort the results based on his like such as sort by **Proc Percentage** or **Proc Fees**.

However, Results have to displayed under one column only with title : "**Proc Charges**".

Thus, if user selects Sort by `Proc_Percentages`, I would like to show results in following order.

Sample Results when Sort if based on Percentage

**Proc Charges**

---

```
1: 0.5%

2: 1.0% 

3: 1.5%*

4: 2345

5: 1234

6: 678
```

Here order of only 1 to 3 matters (PERCENTAGE Sorting). Row 4 to 6 can come in any order.

On the other end, if user selects Sort by Proc_Fees, I would like to show results in following order.

Sample Results when Sort if based on Percentage

**Proc Charges**

---

```
1: 678

2: 1234 

3: 2345*

4: 1%

5: 1.5%

6: 0.5%
```

Here order of only 1 to 3 matters (FEES Sorting). Row 4 to 6 can come in any order.

Can someone explaing me how can I achieve this? I tried to use order by `perd desc, fees asc` but did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

**For Proc_Percentage**

```
SELECT * FROM 
TableName 
Order By CASE WHEN LOCATE('%',ColumnName)>0 Then 1 Else 999999;
```

**For Proc_Fees**

```
SELECT * FROM 
TableName 
Order By CASE WHEN LOCATE('%',ColumnName)>0 Then 999999 Else 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
order by ifnull($selected_column, 999999) asc
```